# pygame: creating window display freezes everything

Tags: python, pygame, virtualbox

I've seen a number of similar questions out there, but none of the solutions have worked for me. This is incredibly simple, so perhaps I'm overlooking something trivial.

My code (create a display window in pygame):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
```

When I run this file from the terminal (python file_name.py) the entire screen freezes and I have to reboot (power off my virtual machine). However, if I write these lines of code in python within the terminal directly, the window pops open as it should. What's the deal with that?

What I've tried: Putting the last line a while loop, putting this into a main function, and using time.sleep() to delay before the program ends.

python 3.7.4, pygame 2.0.0, Debian 10.3.0 (running within virtualBox 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

Your application works well. However, you haven't implemented an application loop:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    
    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # update game objects
    # [...]

    # clear display
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # draw game objects
    # [...]

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd> See also [Event and application loop](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_event_and_application_loop.md)